# Fortran end of file error

Tags: arrays, input, io, fortran

I am learning about Fortran and currently doing the exercise on fortrantutorials.com.  I have to run the following code:

```
program magic    
  implicit none
  real, dimension(100) :: a,b,c,d
  open(10, file='data.txt')
  read(10,*) a
  b = a*10
  c = b-a
  d = 1
  print*, 'a = ', a
  print*, 'b = ', b
  print*, 'c = ', c
  print*, 'd = ', d
end program magic
```

It reads the following data.txt file:

```
24
45
67
89
12
99
33
68
37
11
```

When I run it, it shows this error:

```
At line 6 of file test.f95 (unit = 10, file = 'data.txt')
Fortran runtime error: End of file
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 2]
```

Line 6 refers to the following line, and I have double checked that the 'data.txt' and my fortran file are indeed in the same directory:

```
read(10,*) a
```

What can I do to resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does data.txt have (at least) 100 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read(10,*) a
```

tries to read 100 numbers, because size of `a` is 100

```
real, dimension(100) :: a
```

Your file does not contain 100 numbers, so it crashes when it reaches the end of the file.

Just read the message the compiler tells you:

> "Fortran runtime error: End of file"

Answer (score 1):

If you add `IOSTAT=<scalar-int-variable>` to your read, it will set that variable instead of crashing:

```
  integer :: IOSTAT
  CHARACTER*(128) :: IOMSG
  open(10, file='data.txt')
  read(10,*,IOSTAT=IOSTAT,IOMSG=IOMSG) a
  IF ( IOSTAT .NE. 0 ) THEN
     WRITE(*,*) "WARNING: Read failed with message '", TRIM(IOMSG), "'"
  END IF
```

Do not trust the results of such a failed READ statement.